# Problems with Collections.Sort() in Java

Tags: java, compare

i already googled the problem but it seems that everyone has an other issue. Maybe someone can help me:

I always get this Error Message at some (random) point:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:740)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:477)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:402)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:209)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:141)
at com.mygdx.game.GdxGame.render(GdxGame.java:187)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

and this is my compare method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Entity entity) {
    return (int)(entity.y - y);
}
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: I think @AndrewTobilko is probably on to the right answer. The dodgy looking cast to `int` is quite possibly what is making your `compareTo` method non-transitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are getting an overflow/underflow resulting in a comparison which is not always as intended. i.e. if the difference between `entity.y` and `y` >= 2<sup>31</sup> it will overflow and have the opposite sign to what it should. I suggest you use

```
public int compareTo(Entity entity) {
    return Long.compare(entity.y, y);
}
```

or

```
public int compareTo(Entity entity) {
    return entity.y > y ? +1 : entity.y < y ? -1 : 0;
}
```